# Magento Applying tax class to all products

Tags: magento-1.7

how in Magento 1.7 we can apply tax class to all products via SQL
Below is sql query which i hope that i need to run to get this done

```
 UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_int` SET `value` =2 WHERE `attribute_id` =81;
```

i am unable to find attribute id for for tax class attribute? Any help on this

or i am also open to entirely different solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Log in to your admin panel, then select

```
Catalog->Manage Products
```

Then you can click `Select All`, and from the `Actions` drop down on the right, choose `Update Attributes`.

Here you can choose the tax class and update all products in one go.

[image]

Comment: tax class id attribute isn't available in this method

Comment: I've added a screenshot to the answer. If you can't see this, then I would imagine that you're selecting a product/s that are a part of an attribute set where tax_class has been removed. In which case, you need to address that first.

Comment: Is the possible apply tax by SKU wise?

Answer (score 9):

You can do it by code: 
Create a file called `taxclass.php` on the same level as `index.php` with the following content.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0); 
Mage::app();

$productIds = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->getAllIds();

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
    $productIds, 
    array('tax_class_id' => 2),
    0
);
```

If you still want to do it in a query you can identify the tax class attribute like this:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    eav_attribute
WHERE 
    attribute_code = 'tax_class_id' AND
    entity_type_id = (SELECT entity_type_id FROM eav_entity_type where entity_type_code = 'catalog_product')
```

then run your update with the attribute id your find. But this won't work if you have products that don't have a class id set.

Comment: to do this via code where should i put that code overide ?

Comment: You can put the code in one of the upgrade scripts of any module you create, or you can put it in a simple php file and run that in the  browser. See my update to the answer

Comment: Very nice :) This is a very neat way.

Comment: Which one is best frist or second ?

Comment: @SaurabhJain  Neither. Better use the accepted answer. But if you want to do it via code, better use first one to avoid direct queries.

Answer (score 1):

Open Magento admin, Go to the catalog manage products section. Then click on select all and go to mass action dropdown and selection update attribute and apply.

Then a new window will open then apply changes in text class attribute.

Answer (score 1):

To find attribute ID

1. In your database and find your **eav_attribute** table execute below query

   SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_code` LIKE 'tax_class_id'
2. You can get attribute id  by above sql query
3. By using that you can execute this sql

   UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_int` SET `value` =2 WHERE `attribute_id` = your_attribute_id;