# How can i add 5% amount on if customer choose Online Payment instead of cod

Tags: magento-1.9, custom

How can i apply extra fees if customer choose online payment instead of cash on delivery.

Comment: you can set tax amount

Comment: could u pls explain briefly.

Comment: tax amount will be added in your subtotal so you can set Tax amount.

Comment: How can i set 5% tax amount for my all order.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17735/magento-applying-tax-class-to-all-products this may help you .

Comment: Where i can give tax %

Comment: bro i forget to share one thing, who are all going to pay through online transaction, there only apply this rule, not for all customer. If customer choose cod or bank deposit, tax not applied.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48387/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-ronak-chauhan).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i apply extra 5% cost of Total order value](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/145538/how-can-i-apply-extra-5-cost-of-total-order-value)

Answer (score 0):

You can set tax from (First set tax zone and then set tax rule):
Sales->Tax
[image]

Comment: who are all going to pay through online transaction, there only apply this rule, not for all customer. If customer choose cod or bank deposit, tax not applied.

Comment: you can create custom tax class for that